# Using this keyword in Javascript with prototypes?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, jasmine

When I try to use `this` in my Javascript prototype like so:

```
Array.prototype.sample = function() {
  return this[Math.floor (Math.random() * this.length )];
}
```

As well as implement my tests ([Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)):

```
describe('sample()', function() {
  it('returns a random item of an array', function() {
    orig_array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux'];
    sampled_word = orig_array.sample(); 
    expect(orig_array).toContain(sampled_word);
  });
});
```

My test fails. These methods were originally functions using arguments to process the `this` keyword inside of the prototype, but due to the fact that this is going to be in a small Javascript library, I'd rather implement it as a prototype. Is the `this` keyword correct in this context, or is there a error with the prototype I'm not getting? Thanks.

Comment: *ReferenceError: array is not defined*

Comment: @CrescentFresh Fixed, but the test is still failing. It says: `TypeError: Object foo,bar,baz,qux has no method 'sample'`.

Comment: Please fix your question to show the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code.

```
Array.prototype.sample = function() {
   return this[Math.floor (Math.random() * array.length )];
}
```

Simply 'array' is not defined. The code which should work is

```
Array.prototype.sample = function() {
   return this[Math.floor (Math.random() * this.length )];
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, multiple errors in some previous code located in the same file. Should be resumed shortly now. Thanks for the help.